Relation between Dyson equation, Kadanoff-Baym equations and 2PI formalism
I am learning the framework of non-equilibrium field theory. Probably this is clear enough to an expert, but the expansive number of formalism, methods, and frameworks is confusing for a beginner.
I am confused about the relationship between the Dyson equation, the Kadanoff–Baym equations, and the 2PI formalism.
Is the following summary correct?

At the most basic level, one can compute a sum of self-energy diagrams $\Sigma(x, x')$
There are potentially pinch singularities, so one should resum these self-energy diagrams to produced a dressed propagator $G(x,x')$. This is the role of the Dyson equation. It involves an integral of $\Sigma$ over all intermediate times $t$, even those to the future of the times associated with $x$, $x'$ in $G(x,x')$
The Kadanoff–Baym equations are equivalent to the Dyson equation, but expressed in terms of the retarded/advanced Green's function, the statistical function $F$ and the spectral function $\rho$. Expressed in terms of $F$ and $\rho$, they are explicitly causal, even though this wasn't apparent at the level of the Dyson equation.
The 2PI framework is not needed to derive any of these equations (although it can be used to do so). Instead, the point of the 2PI formalism is that the resummation performed by the "ordinary" Dyson equation is not self-consistent in that it does not include foam ("super-daisy", "Hartree–Fock") diagrams.

But it is not very clear what is actually different about the Kadanoff–Baym equations in the 2PI framework. Is it simply that I should evaluate the self-energy $\Sigma(x,x')$ using the full dressed propagator, and drop self-energy insertions? This seems to be what is meant when people talk about 2PI skeleton diagrams.
This prescription at least appears to be what is implied by Eqs (2.6)–(2.7) of Berges, Controlled nonperturbative dynamics of quantum fields out of equilibrium, or Eqs. (7)–(10) of Lindner & Muller, Comparison of Boltzmann Equations with Quantum Dynamics for Scalar Fields.
If so, what is the advantage of the whole 2PI machinery beyond that 1-sentence prescription? (Perhaps for calculation of higher order correlation functions?)

Let us first look at the relation between Dyson and Kadanoff–Baym (KB) equation.
Depending on the context different equations are meant. First, I take it as the equations, which tells you given a self-energy how to compute a Green function, namely here
$
\text{Dyson} \qquad \qquad  \quad:   G = G_0 + G_0 * \Sigma * G \\
\text{Kadanoff–Baym} \,\,\,\, : { G_0^{-1}} * G = \delta + \Sigma * G
$
Firstly, to your second point, it is not true that the integrals in the Dyson equation would run over times in the future of x or x'. Note here that the $*-$ multiplications are integrals to be performed around the Keldysh contour, which then enforces causality. In principle, both equations are completely equivalent.
For most non-equilibrium problems, the KB form is more useful for two main reasons. Firstly, it gives you an equation of motion with a time derivative in $G_0^{-1}$, which is good for numerical integration. In the Dyson form, a self-consistency needs to be applied, and more integrals have to be evaluated. Secondly, in the Dyson form $G_0$ must be known, which sounds like a somewhat trivial task, but is not clear how to do. Depending what field representation you use in the free propagators, also the Keldysh component or in (+,-) representation all components depend explicitly on the initial state. Therefore most calculations try to avoid ever using $G_0$ and stick with its inverse.
As a short note here, sometimes the eom. in average time (t+t') of the lesser Green function $G^<(t,t')$ are also called the KB equation. You can easily obtain them from the KB equation I stated at the top.
Now, we move to the second part, which relates something else from Kadanoff-Baym to 2PI. Baym and Kadanoff have shown that if you generate your self-energies from a functional with full Green functions by a derivative, it will fulfil conservation laws. The question remains: how do you get the functional from which you take derivatives? This is also called the Luttinger-Ward functional $\Phi$ or in the 2PI context usually $\Gamma^2$.
The 2PI EA is a method to generate these diagrammatic contributions systematically. It boils down to eq. (2.19) in Phys. Rev. D 10, 2428 , which essentially gives you the expression to generate all 2PI/skeleton diagrams. The point is you can now also start to expand this expression in different ways, focusing on $\hbar$ or coupling constants or field components or density and much more.
Another point is that it includes the 1-point averages. This also allows you to naturally derive equations of motion for it, which are useful for BEC's. Here one should note that in these cases the 2PI EA tells us that $G_0^{-1}$ will have contributions from the interaction and new verticies will appear in the theory. These are rather hard to argue in other constructions.
